# Synchronizing iphone with web interface?

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, synchronization

If I have both a web interface and a iOS application, what techniques could I use to make sure the data is sychronized between the two?

I'm looking for something that isn't overly complicated, and might not be a solution that works 100% of the time, but something reasonable.

So the scenerio is, someone uses the web interface while their iphone app is open, and say ads some data.  Say this is a grocery list application, and they added 'bananas' to a list.

Now the iphone is not in synch with the changes made on the web interface.

What should/could i do in this case?

**Update**

Data will be stored in mysql, and ideally some will be cached locally on the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is a classic synchronisation problem between a mobile device and web service.

On a high level, a classic solution would be to poll for data every x seconds on your mobile device to your web service to see if there are any updates (where you base 'x' on the level of synchronization you need taking into consideration that lower values put more strain on data transfer and thus require more battery power). In order to submit changes from the mobile device to your webservice, you could require that a data connection be available so that when data is entered, it is instantly submitted to your webservice or you could queue it so when a data connection is available, it batch sends the requests to the webservice and the webservice handles conflicting data based on timestamps or some other metric.

Comment: not looking for a polling solution, was hoping for something like hashing the content etc.

Comment: Do you mean caching? If so, you can add that into your polling solution so when you poll it asks for changes made to your database after a specific timestamp and that'll give you a list of changes which you then apply to the cached side. It requires a bit more effort but definitely will make your app less bandwidth intensive